# ExtJs 3.4 : set label border, center label text and bold label text

Tags: javascript, extjs, label

I have an ExtJs label in a field set and I am using ExtJs 3.4.

```
{
                xtype : 'fieldset',
                layout : 'hbox',
                border : false,
                defaults : {
                    //layout : 'hbox',
                    labelAlign : 'center'
                },
                items : [ {
                    xtype : 'label',
                    id : 'idOpen',
                    text : '',
                    width : 52.5,
                    height : 25,
                    labelStyle : 'font-weight:bold;',
                    border : true,
                    style : {
                        //background : '#6699FF',
                        color : 'black',
                        textAlign: 'center'
                    }
                }.......
```

I need to add border to that label and bold label text. I've tried **border : true** but it's nor working.

**labelStyle : 'font-weight:bold;'** is also not working.

And also I need to center label text within the label box. I've tried

```
style : {

                        textAlign: 'center'
                    }
```

It center t5he text horizontally but not vertically.

How can I fix these issues ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{
    xtype : 'label',
    id : 'idOpen',
    text: '...', // some default value to render label correctly
    cls: 'my-label-style'
}
```

in your .css file:

```
.my-label-style {
    font-weight: bold; 
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
}
```

To set label text

```
Ext.getCmp('idOpen').setText('Oh, this is my new text');
```

Comment: my label text is getting from database. is it ok?

Comment: how can I add textAlign for this style ?

Comment: i also need to add font color and txt align

Comment: My text is align horizontally within the box. but I want to center the label text both horizontally and vertical

Comment: You gonna play with padding in case of using label component. You can try to use xtype:'container' with border and place your label everywhere you want.